# included translation inside block in email template

Tags: magento2, blocks, email-templates, email-translation

I'm wondering does it's possible to use translation inside the block that include in email template. It's my piece of code email template:

```
{{block class='Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/shipment-link.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order }}
```

that block inside translation like that:

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shipped By') ?>
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Tracking Number') ?>
```

and inside my file pl_PL.csv I have translation:

```
"Tracking Number","Numer śledzenia",module,Magento_Sales
"Tracking Number","Numer śledzenia",module,Magento_Shipment
"Tracking Number","Numer śledzenia",theme,frontend/MyVendor/B2C
"Tracking Number","Numer śledzenia",theme,frontend/Magento/luma
"Tracking Number","Numer śledzenia",theme,frontend/Magento/blank
```

neither of them works... Do you have any solution for that problem?